# Given a Java InputStream, how can I determine the current offset in the stream?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

I'd like something like a generic, re-usable `getPosition()` method that will tell me the number of bytes read from the starting point of the stream.  Ideally, I would prefer this to work with all InputStreams, so that I don't have to wrap each and every one of them as I get them from disparate sources.

Does such a beast exist?  If not, can anyone recommend an existing implementation of a counting `InputStream`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at [CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html) in the Commons IO package. They have a pretty good collection of other useful InputStream variants as well.

Answer (score 23):

You'll need to follow the Decorator pattern established in `java.io` to implement this.

Let's give it a try here:

```
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public final class PositionInputStream
  extends FilterInputStream
{

  private long pos = 0;

  private long mark = 0;

  public PositionInputStream(InputStream in)
  {
    super(in);
  }

  /**
   * <p>Get the stream position.</p>
   *
   * <p>Eventually, the position will roll over to a negative number.
   * Reading 1 Tb per second, this would occur after approximately three 
   * months. Applications should account for this possibility in their 
   * design.</p>
   *
   * @return the current stream position.
   */
  public synchronized long getPosition()
  {
    return pos;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized int read()
    throws IOException
  {
    int b = super.read();
    if (b >= 0)
      pos += 1;
    return b;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)
    throws IOException
  {
    int n = super.read(b, off, len);
    if (n > 0)
      pos += n;
    return n;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized long skip(long skip)
    throws IOException
  {
    long n = super.skip(skip);
    if (n > 0)
      pos += n;
    return n;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void mark(int readlimit)
  {
    super.mark(readlimit);
    mark = pos;
  }

  @Override
  public synchronized void reset()
    throws IOException
  {
    /* A call to reset can still succeed if mark is not supported, but the 
     * resulting stream position is undefined, so it's not allowed here. */
    if (!markSupported())
      throw new IOException("Mark not supported.");
    super.reset();
    pos = mark;
  }

}
```

The InputStreams are intended to be thread safe, so that accounts for the liberal use of synchronization. I played around with `volatile` and `AtomicLong` position variables, but synchronization is probably best because it allows one thread to operate on the stream and query its position without relinquishing the lock.

```
PositionInputStream is = …
synchronized (is) {
  is.read(buf);
  pos = is.getPosition();
}
```

Comment: Decorator pattern is a nice solution for this one, voting it up.

One option would be to remove synchronized and document that the implementation is not thread safe. A caller that does read() and then checks the position has to synchronize anyway to achieve usable (atomic) behaviour.

Comment: I don't suppose that anyone knows of an implementation of this already extant?  It seems like NIH syndrome to reimplement what must be a very common requirement.

Comment: I like the idea and it is easily pluggable to an application. However, there is a serious problem that users of this class should know about: if a buffered reader uses this class, then the reported position is false as the data is read in buckets and not byte by byte.

Comment: @Asterios - The reported position is always correct *for the stream*; an `InputStreamReader` is just like anything else reading the stream. You cannot expect the stream to track what its clients are doing with the data that they consume (that is, how many bytes that a `Reader` has read have actually been examined by the `Reader`). That sort of functionality would have to be built into the `Reader`.

Comment: "Reading 1 Tb per second, this would occur after approximately three months." - my InputStream will definitely last that long :P

Comment: Does the job for me. Also easily implemented, and for an amateur like me, that's great.

Answer (score 4):

There is also `CountingInputStream` in [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

Apidocs: 
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/CountingInputStream.html

Source: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/io/CountingInputStream.java

Answer (score 2):

No. `InputStream` is intended to handle potentially infinite amounts of data, so a counter would get in the way. In addition to wrapping them all, you might be able to do something with aspects.