# How to synchronize the progress with the time of the program?

Tags: java, file, time, progress

I was trying to make the progress work in time with the program, while it's time goes on.

In the below code the progress is working but just inside the for loop.
How to let the progress grow with the task of the program ?

```
private void readFromFile(File cf2) throws IOException, Exception {
    //System.out.println("okay");
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(cf2);
    try (BufferedReader bw = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
        System.out.println("Wait while reading !");
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= 100 ; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.print(String.format("[%s]%d%%\r", progress(i), i));
        }
        while(bw.readLine() != null)
        s1 += bw.readLine();
    }
}

private static final StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();

static String progress(int pct) {
    res.delete(0, res.length());
    int numPounds = (pct + 9) / 10;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != numPounds ; i++) {
        res.append('#');
    }
    while (res.length() != 10) {
        res.append(' ');
    }
    return res.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that you would like to print the percentage of bytes read from the input file?

Comment: yes, I tried to say it.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/240431/2032064). All you need to add is (1) getting the total file size using `File#length()`, (2) add percentage printing to the `read()` method.

Comment: I understand it in part. May you give a code example ?