# Query on xml file with special case

Tags: java, xml

I have 2 large files which I gather from Stackoverflow named `posts.xml` and `questions.txt` with the following structure:

**posts.xml:**

```
<posts>
  <row Id="4" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="7" CreationDate="2008-07-31T21:42:52.667" Score="322" ViewCount="21888" Body="..."/>
  <row Id="6" PostTypeId="1" AcceptedAnswerId="31" CreationDate="2008-07-31T22:08:08.620" Score="140" ViewCount="10912" Body="..." />
  ...
</posts>
```

A post can be question or answer (both)

**questions.txt:**

```
Id,CreationDate,CreationDatesk,Score
123,2008-08-01 16:08:52,20080801,48
126,2008-08-01 16:10:30,20080801,33
...
```

I wanna query on posts just one time and index the selected rows (which their ID is in `questions.txt` file) with lucene. Since the xml file is very large (about 50GB), the time of querying and indexing is important for me.

Now the question is: How can I find all the selected rows in `posts.xml` that are repeated in `questions.txt`

This is my approach until now:

**SAXParserDemo.java:**

```
public class SAXParserDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        try {
            File inputFile = new File("D:\\University\\Information Retrieval 2\\Hws\\Hw1\\files\\Posts.xml");
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            UserHandler userhandler = new UserHandler();
            saxParser.parse(inputFile, userhandler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Handler.java:**

```
public class Handler extends DefaultHandler {

    public void getQuestiondId() {
        ArrayList<String> qIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String qId;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\University\\Information Retrieval 2\\Hws\\Hw1\\files\\Q.txt"));
            while ((qId = br.readLine()) != null) {
                qId = qId.split(",")[0];  //this is question id
                findAndIndexOnPost(qId);    //find this id on posts.xml then index it!
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void findAndIndexOnPost(String qID) {

    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri,
                             String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("row")) {
            System.out.println(attributes.getValue("Id"));
            switch (attributes.getValue("PostTypeId")) {
                case "1":
                    String id = attributes.getValue("Id");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I need to keep pointer on xml file in every iteration. But with SAX I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is:

- read the TXT file (probably a simple stream will do).
- add all `Id` values to a `List<Integer> questionIds` - one by one. You will have to parse them manually (with a regex or `String.indexOf()`).
- in your Handler implementation simply compare if `questionIds.contains(givenId)`.
- send the received object (from XML) to Elastic Search with a simple REST request (POST/PUT).

Ta-da! Your data is now indexed with lucene.

Also, change the way you pass data to SAX Parser. Instead of giving it a `File`, create an implementation of `InputStream` for it which you can give to `saxParser.parse(inputStream, userhandler);`. Info on getting position in a stream here: [Given a Java InputStream, how can I determine the current offset in the stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240294/given-a-java-inputstream-how-can-i-determine-the-current-offset-in-the-stream).

Comment: thanks, I already do something like this and it's getting work! Although I've used `HashSet<String>` instead of `List<Integer>` Since I heard that the order of it's `contains` method is `O(1)`. Does it?